# Assign a list to new column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda Dataframe which is composed of just one column called "name". I have been searching how to iterate over the rows of dataframe to get the value of name, and in the same row add another column called "vectors" that will store a list of vectors in each row.

For instance, the value to be saved in the column "vectors" is returning an array of 300 numbers from "avg_sentence_vector" function:

```
def avg_sentence_vector(words, model, num_features, index2word_set):
    #function to average all words vectors in a given paragraph
    featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float32")
    nwords = 0

    for word in words:
        if word in index2word_set:
            nwords = nwords+1
            featureVec = np.add(featureVec, model[word])

    if nwords>0:
        featureVec = np.divide(featureVec, nwords)
    return featureVec
```

The original dataframe has just one column "name" which contains several rows of names:

```
name    object
dtype: object
```

I iterate over the dataframe as follows:

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    # access data using column names
    name_n=row['name']
    #This returns a list of vectors of float32
    name_avg_vector = avg_sentence_vector(name_n.split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist()
    df2.loc[df2.index[index],'vectors']=name_avg_vector
```

However, I am getting the error: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

I also tried to assign the value as follows:

```
df2.iloc[index, df2.columns.get_loc('vectors')]=name_avg_vector
```

How can I add the value coming from name_avg_vector in the new column "avg_vector" with the corresponding value in each iteration?

**Update:**

As @Peruz suggested I changed the loop included previously (the objective was to iterate over the dataframe to get the words coming from name and invoke avg_sentence_vector function) and the three lines including the for loop were condensed to this single line:

```
df2[['vectors']]= df2[['vectors']].apply(avg_sentence_vector(df.name.str.split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist())
```

However, after the change I am searching how to solve the new error:
***unhashable type: 'list'***

**Update2:**

I keep getting unhashable type: 'list', I tried very basic scenario with the following results:

Snippet A:

```
name = "4 PAWS ONLY"
vectors = avg_sentence_vector(name.split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist()
```

*Snippet A works successfully.*

Snippet B:

```
name = ['4 PAWS ONLY']
ndf = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=range(1), columns=['name', 'vectors'])
ndf['name'] = name

ndf[['vectors']]=ndf[['vectors']].applymap(avg_sentence_vector(ndf.name.str.split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist())
```

*Snippet B throws the error **unhashable type: 'list'***

Thanks

Comment: What's the shape of `name_avg_vector`? Also, what's the shape of `df2`?

Comment: ... yes the optimal solution depends a bit on the actual shape (len in this case) of the DataFrame, next time add this information please.

Comment: The shape of name_avg_vector is 300 and the shape of df2 is (10000, 2) where the dataframe has two columns with 10000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

it seems your list depends just on the *names* column, comment if I'm wrong.
Then, `Pandas.DataFrame.apply()` (see also `map()`) may be sufficient, unless you have to handle higher complexity.

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['v1', 've2', 'vec3', 'vect4']
ndf = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=range(4), columns=['names', 'added'])
ndf['names'] = names
ndf['added'] = ndf['names'].apply(len) # change len with your function and you can pass additional arguments too
```

I hope this helps and that I'm not missing the key reason why you were for-looping, which as you likely know isn't efficient with `iterrows()`.

**Edit**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def simple_function(l, num_features, extra_v):
    v = len(l)
    featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float32")
    featureVec += v
    featureVec += extra_v
    featureVec /= 2
    return(featureVec)

names = ['v1', 've2', 'vec3', 'vect4']
ndf = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=range(4), columns=['names', 'added'])
ndf['names'] = names
ndf['added'] = ndf['names'].apply(simple_function, args=(5, 2))
print(ndf)
```

Comment: Thanks Peruz, after applying apply in the dataframe, I am getting unhashable type: 'list', I am looking into it to figure out what is the cause of the error after the change. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I edited the answer to add a simple function in line with yours. The example works, although it isn't your complete function, which requires/takes specific args. Regarding the error, make sure you don't pass the list to a dictionary (for example to model, which seems to be a dict). I'm guessing a bit based on the available information. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Peruz, I updated an additional finding through conducting a very basic scenario which works with string, but is not working when using dataframe. Thanks for your your help.

Comment: I don't have all the material to reproduce it. I think your error is unrelated and it requires a minimal workable example, likely in a new post so that the topic will be coherent with the title. Best